# Using java.util.Map in AXIS@ framework

Tags: dictionary, apache-axis

I am using AXIS2 Framework for creating and accesing a webservice. My question is Is AXIS2 supports java.util.Map data type. I want use this data type in response.xml.

Thanks,
Narendra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't use any of the java Collection classes.  Using arrays of objects works best.